# How to remove a header from express req object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to figure out how to remove header from `req` object in express. I believe this `res.disable("Header Name")` removes it from res object, but same doesn't work for `req.headers`

Comment: Why do you want to edit the req object? It represents the request made by the client

Comment: You can delete it like you delete any other property of a normal JavaScript object, but it doesn't affect the actual request in any case. Only the middlewares yet to come in the path of your request won't see those headers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That could be as simple as adding this middleware:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  delete req.headers['header-name']; // should be lowercase
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `delete` headers from your `request` object, like i am doing below-

```
console.log(req.headers)

// { host: 'localhost:8081',
//   connection: 'keep-alive',
//   auth_token: 'c79d2f80029c1a1382b2e831643e5447b902a6f9',
//   'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.100 Safari/537.36',
//   'postman-token': 'b2cef620-f85d-556c-acc1-8337da2d5e81',
//   'cache-control': 'no-cache',
//   api_key: 'FB499A4FF77901AFCD2278457658B7F7B17EAC112B489DAA304D3F2A059DFCC4',
//   'content-type': 'application/json',
//   accept: '*/*',
//   dnt: '1',
//   'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
//   'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8' }

// Now Delete the headers from your request object.

delete req.headers;

console.log(req.headers) // undefined
```

If you want to remove any key from header then use below code:

```
delete req.headers['auth_token'];
```